php generate qrcode as .eps using chillerlan/php-qrcode library for use as a vector graphic
I'm using the chillerlan php-qrcode library to generate a qrcode. With my current code it generates a new file "qrcode.eps" in the same folder as my controller. But when I looked into the file, I noticed that the file only contains xml code for svg. I need the library to generate the qrcode as a real .eps so our design department can use the .eps file for Adobe Illustrator.
Controller with qrCode generation.
public function generateQrCode(string $url, string $qrCodeType): string
    {
        $options = new QROptions();

        $options->version           = 7;
        $options->outputInterface   = QREps::class;
        $options->scale             = 5;
        $options->drawLightModules  = false;
        $options->bgColor           = [222, 222, 222];
        $options->moduleValues      = [
            // finder
            QRMatrix::M_FINDER_DARK    => [0, 63, 255],    // dark (true)
            QRMatrix::M_FINDER_DOT     => [0, 63, 255],    // finder dot, dark (true)
            QRMatrix::M_FINDER         => [233, 233, 233], // light (false)
            // alignment
            QRMatrix::M_ALIGNMENT_DARK => [255, 0, 255],
            QRMatrix::M_ALIGNMENT      => [233, 233, 233],
            // timing
            QRMatrix::M_TIMING_DARK    => [255, 0, 0],
            QRMatrix::M_TIMING         => [233, 233, 233],
            // format
            QRMatrix::M_FORMAT_DARK    => [67, 159, 84],
            QRMatrix::M_FORMAT         => [233, 233, 233],
            // version
            QRMatrix::M_VERSION_DARK   => [62, 174, 190],
            QRMatrix::M_VERSION        => [233, 233, 233],
            // data
            QRMatrix::M_DATA_DARK      => [0, 0, 0],
            QRMatrix::M_DATA           => [233, 233, 233],
            // darkmodule
            QRMatrix::M_DARKMODULE     => [0, 0, 0],
            // separator
            QRMatrix::M_SEPARATOR      => [233, 233, 233],
            // quietzone
            QRMatrix::M_QUIETZONE      => [233, 233, 233],
            // logo space (requires a call to QRMatrix::setLogoSpace()), see imageWithLogo example
            QRMatrix::M_LOGO           => [233, 233, 233],
        ];

        $qrcode = (new QRCode($options))->render($url, __DIR__ . '/qrcode.eps');

        if(php_sapi_name() !== 'cli'){
            // Muss als File Download gesendet werden, da Browser normalerweise EPS nicht unterstützt
            header('Content-type: application/postscript');
            header('Content-Disposition: filename="qrcode.eps"');
        }

        return $qrcode;
    }

qrcode.eps
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="qr-svg qrcode" viewBox="0 0 53 53" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
<path class="qr-darkmodule dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M12 41 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-data-dark dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M14 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 12 h1 v1 h-1Z
M40 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M11 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 13 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 15 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 17 h1 v1 h-1Z
M25 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 17 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 19 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M11 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 21 h1 v1 h-1Z
M40 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 21 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 23 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 28 h1 v1 h-1Z
M17 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 29 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 31 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 32 h1 v1 h-1Z
M47 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 33 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 35 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 37 h1 v1 h-1Z
M18 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 37 h1 v1 h-1Z M11 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M11 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 44 h1 v1 h-1Z
M14 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M15 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M17 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M21 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M29 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M33 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M13 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M19 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M23 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M31 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M35 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M37 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 48 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-finder-dark dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M4 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 48 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 48 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-alignment-dark dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M24 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 11 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M11 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 24 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 25 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 26 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 27 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M11 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 28 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 41 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 42 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M24 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M25 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M26 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M27 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M28 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M41 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M42 44 h1 v1 h-1Z
M43 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 44 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-timing-dark dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M12 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M14 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M16 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M18 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M20 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M22 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M30 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M32 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M34 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M36 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 10 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 14 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 16 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 18 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 20 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 22 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 30 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 32 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 34 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 36 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M10 40 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-format-dark dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M12 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 9 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M9 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M43 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M47 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M48 12 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 43 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 47 h1 v1 h-1Z M12 48 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-version-dark dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M40 4 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 5 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M38 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M39 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M40 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 38 h1 v1 h-1Z M5 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 39 h1 v1 h-1Z M4 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 40 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 40 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
<path class="qr-finder-dot dark qrcode" fill="#000" d="M6 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 6 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 7 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M44 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M45 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M46 8 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 44 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 45 h1 v1 h-1Z M6 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M7 46 h1 v1 h-1Z M8 46 h1 v1 h-1Z"/>
</svg>



If you follow the exact demo at https://php-qrcode.readthedocs.io/en/main/Built-In-Output/QREps.html does it also produce the wrong content in the file? If so then I'd suggest raising a ticket with the maintainer of the library

Just tested and yes. Guess I'll raise a ticket then.

Just a side note: Adobe Illustrator can open SVG files since ~20years. Adobe Indesign CC added support for placing/importing SVG ~ 2019/20. In case the eps output still fails you may also opt for pdf output. There's no real advantage to using the .eps format, but many older graphic designers still think it's the best vector format.

@herrstrietzel Your last sentence is the problem. Our design department only works with .eps...

//just replace this:
//use chillerlan\QRCode\Output\QREps;
//with this:
use chillerlan\QRCode\Output\QROutputInterface;
//============================================
//and this :
//$options->outputInterface  = QREps::class;
//with this:
$options->outputType= QROutputInterface::EPS;

check this:
<?php

use chillerlan\QRCode\{QRCode, QROptions};
use chillerlan\QRCode\Data\QRMatrix;
//just replace this:
//use chillerlan\QRCode\Output\QREps;
//with this:
use chillerlan\QRCode\Output\QROutputInterface;

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

$options = new QROptions;

$options->version          = 7;
//and this :
//$options->outputInterface  = QREps::class;
//with this:
$options->outputType= QROutputInterface::EPS;
$options->scale            = 5;
$options->drawLightModules = false;
// colors can be specified either as [R, G, B] or [C, M, Y, K] (0-255)
$options->bgColor          = [222, 222, 222];
$options->moduleValues     = [
  // finder
  QRMatrix::M_FINDER_DARK    => [0, 63, 255],    // dark (true)
  QRMatrix::M_FINDER_DOT     => [0, 63, 255],    // finder dot, dark (true)
  QRMatrix::M_FINDER         => [233, 233, 233], // light (false)
  // alignment
  QRMatrix::M_ALIGNMENT_DARK => [255, 0, 255],
  QRMatrix::M_ALIGNMENT      => [233, 233, 233],
  // timing
  QRMatrix::M_TIMING_DARK    => [255, 0, 0],
  QRMatrix::M_TIMING         => [233, 233, 233],
  // format
  QRMatrix::M_FORMAT_DARK    => [67, 159, 84],
  QRMatrix::M_FORMAT         => [233, 233, 233],
  // version
  QRMatrix::M_VERSION_DARK   => [62, 174, 190],
  QRMatrix::M_VERSION        => [233, 233, 233],
  // data
  QRMatrix::M_DATA_DARK      => [0, 0, 0],
  QRMatrix::M_DATA           => [233, 233, 233],
  // darkmodule
  QRMatrix::M_DARKMODULE     => [0, 0, 0],
  // separator
  QRMatrix::M_SEPARATOR      => [233, 233, 233],
  // quietzone
  QRMatrix::M_QUIETZONE      => [233, 233, 233],
  // logo space (requires a call to QRMatrix::setLogoSpace()), see imageWithLogo example
  QRMatrix::M_LOGO           => [233, 233, 233],
];


$out = (new QRCode($options))->render('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ', __DIR__.'/qrcode.eps');

if(php_sapi_name() !== 'cli'){
  // if viewed in the browser, we should push it as file download as EPS isn't usually supported
  header('Content-type: application/postscript');
  header('Content-Disposition: filename="qrcode.eps"');
}

echo $out;

exit;

EDIT: output (partial just for show the first part of postscript )

EDIT 2: full output result
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: php-qrcode (https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode)
%%Title: QR Code
%%CreationDate: 2024-06-20T08:35:16+00:00
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 3
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 265 265
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
/F { rectfill } def
/R { setrgbcolor } def
/C { setcmykcolor } def
%%EndProlog
0.870588 0.870588 0.870588 R
0 0 265 265 F
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 R
60 55 5 5 F
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 R
65 240 5 5 F
70 240 5 5 F
75 240 5 5 F
100 240 5 5 F
105 240 5 5 F
110 240 5 5 F
125 240 5 5 F
135 240 5 5 F
140 240 5 5 F
145 240 5 5 F
160 240 5 5 F
170 240 5 5 F
70 235 5 5 F
80 235 5 5 F
95 235 5 5 F
100 235 5 5 F
105 235 5 5 F
115 235 5 5 F
140 235 5 5 F
145 235 5 5 F
165 235 5 5 F
180 235 5 5 F
185 235 5 5 F
70 230 5 5 F
85 230 5 5 F
100 230 5 5 F
125 230 5 5 F
135 230 5 5 F
140 230 5 5 F
145 230 5 5 F
150 230 5 5 F
170 230 5 5 F
65 225 5 5 F
70 225 5 5 F
95 225 5 5 F
105 225 5 5 F
115 225 5 5 F
140 225 5 5 F
150 225 5 5 F
155 225 5 5 F
165 225 5 5 F
170 225 5 5 F
175 225 5 5 F
180 225 5 5 F
70 220 5 5 F
80 220 5 5 F
85 220 5 5 F
100 220 5 5 F
110 220 5 5 F
145 220 5 5 F
150 220 5 5 F
170 220 5 5 F
180 220 5 5 F
185 220 5 5 F
65 215 5 5 F
75 215 5 5 F
80 215 5 5 F
95 215 5 5 F
100 215 5 5 F
105 215 5 5 F
155 215 5 5 F
165 215 5 5 F
170 215 5 5 F
175 215 5 5 F
180 215 5 5 F
185 215 5 5 F
70 205 5 5 F
80 205 5 5 F
85 205 5 5 F
100 205 5 5 F
115 205 5 5 F
150 205 5 5 F
155 205 5 5 F
160 205 5 5 F
165 205 5 5 F
180 205 5 5 F
195 205 5 5 F
70 200 5 5 F
80 200 5 5 F
105 200 5 5 F
165 200 5 5 F
175 200 5 5 F
25 195 5 5 F
30 195 5 5 F
35 195 5 5 F
60 195 5 5 F
65 195 5 5 F
75 195 5 5 F
85 195 5 5 F
95 195 5 5 F
110 195 5 5 F
130 195 5 5 F
140 195 5 5 F
145 195 5 5 F
160 195 5 5 F
165 195 5 5 F
170 195 5 5 F
175 195 5 5 F
180 195 5 5 F
185 195 5 5 F
195 195 5 5 F
200 195 5 5 F
220 195 5 5 F
230 195 5 5 F
235 195 5 5 F
240 195 5 5 F
20 190 5 5 F
30 190 5 5 F
45 190 5 5 F
55 190 5 5 F
85 190 5 5 F
90 190 5 5 F
110 190 5 5 F
125 190 5 5 F
130 190 5 5 F
135 190 5 5 F
150 190 5 5 F
165 190 5 5 F
185 190 5 5 F
190 190 5 5 F
210 190 5 5 F
225 190 5 5 F
230 190 5 5 F
235 190 5 5 F
20 185 5 5 F
25 185 5 5 F
35 185 5 5 F
45 185 5 5 F
65 185 5 5 F
70 185 5 5 F
75 185 5 5 F
80 185 5 5 F
90 185 5 5 F
95 185 5 5 F
105 185 5 5 F
110 185 5 5 F
115 185 5 5 F
120 185 5 5 F
130 185 5 5 F
155 185 5 5 F
165 185 5 5 F
175 185 5 5 F
185 185 5 5 F
200 185 5 5 F
215 185 5 5 F
230 185 5 5 F
30 180 5 5 F
40 180 5 5 F
55 180 5 5 F
65 180 5 5 F
70 180 5 5 F
85 180 5 5 F
90 180 5 5 F
110 180 5 5 F
120 180 5 5 F
125 180 5 5 F
135 180 5 5 F
145 180 5 5 F
160 180 5 5 F
195 180 5 5 F
200 180 5 5 F
205 180 5 5 F
220 180 5 5 F
225 180 5 5 F
230 180 5 5 F
235 180 5 5 F
20 175 5 5 F
45 175 5 5 F
55 175 5 5 F
60 175 5 5 F
70 175 5 5 F
75 175 5 5 F
95 175 5 5 F
105 175 5 5 F
110 175 5 5 F
115 175 5 5 F
120 175 5 5 F
130 175 5 5 F
140 175 5 5 F
155 175 5 5 F
160 175 5 5 F
165 175 5 5 F
175 175 5 5 F
185 175 5 5 F
200 175 5 5 F
215 175 5 5 F
220 175 5 5 F
230 175 5 5 F
30 170 5 5 F
40 170 5 5 F
60 170 5 5 F
70 170 5 5 F
75 170 5 5 F
85 170 5 5 F
90 170 5 5 F
110 170 5 5 F
125 170 5 5 F
130 170 5 5 F
135 170 5 5 F
145 170 5 5 F
160 170 5 5 F
170 170 5 5 F
195 170 5 5 F
200 170 5 5 F
205 170 5 5 F
220 170 5 5 F
230 170 5 5 F
235 170 5 5 F
240 170 5 5 F
35 165 5 5 F
45 165 5 5 F
55 165 5 5 F
60 165 5 5 F
65 165 5 5 F
70 165 5 5 F
75 165 5 5 F
90 165 5 5 F
95 165 5 5 F
105 165 5 5 F
110 165 5 5 F
115 165 5 5 F
120 165 5 5 F
130 165 5 5 F
165 165 5 5 F
170 165 5 5 F
180 165 5 5 F
190 165 5 5 F
200 165 5 5 F
205 165 5 5 F
210 165 5 5 F
220 165 5 5 F
225 165 5 5 F
230 165 5 5 F
240 165 5 5 F
25 160 5 5 F
40 160 5 5 F
45 160 5 5 F
60 160 5 5 F
65 160 5 5 F
75 160 5 5 F
80 160 5 5 F
85 160 5 5 F
90 160 5 5 F
95 160 5 5 F
110 160 5 5 F
120 160 5 5 F
125 160 5 5 F
135 160 5 5 F
145 160 5 5 F
150 160 5 5 F
175 160 5 5 F
185 160 5 5 F
190 160 5 5 F
210 160 5 5 F
225 160 5 5 F
235 160 5 5 F
240 160 5 5 F
20 155 5 5 F
30 155 5 5 F
40 155 5 5 F
55 155 5 5 F
60 155 5 5 F
80 155 5 5 F
100 155 5 5 F
105 155 5 5 F
110 155 5 5 F
115 155 5 5 F
120 155 5 5 F
125 155 5 5 F
135 155 5 5 F
140 155 5 5 F
145 155 5 5 F
170 155 5 5 F
195 155 5 5 F
200 155 5 5 F
205 155 5 5 F
220 155 5 5 F
225 155 5 5 F
235 155 5 5 F
240 155 5 5 F
20 150 5 5 F
25 150 5 5 F
35 150 5 5 F
60 150 5 5 F
65 150 5 5 F
95 150 5 5 F
100 150 5 5 F
105 150 5 5 F
115 150 5 5 F
140 150 5 5 F
145 150 5 5 F
155 150 5 5 F
160 150 5 5 F
165 150 5 5 F
175 150 5 5 F
185 150 5 5 F
190 150 5 5 F
195 150 5 5 F
200 150 5 5 F
205 150 5 5 F
210 150 5 5 F
235 150 5 5 F
35 145 5 5 F
40 145 5 5 F
60 145 5 5 F
65 145 5 5 F
75 145 5 5 F
80 145 5 5 F
85 145 5 5 F
100 145 5 5 F
125 145 5 5 F
135 145 5 5 F
140 145 5 5 F
145 145 5 5 F
150 145 5 5 F
170 145 5 5 F
190 145 5 5 F
195 145 5 5 F
200 145 5 5 F
205 145 5 5 F
210 145 5 5 F
225 145 5 5 F
20 140 5 5 F
35 140 5 5 F
80 140 5 5 F
95 140 5 5 F
105 140 5 5 F
115 140 5 5 F
150 140 5 5 F
155 140 5 5 F
165 140 5 5 F
170 140 5 5 F
175 140 5 5 F
180 140 5 5 F
185 140 5 5 F
190 140 5 5 F
230 140 5 5 F
235 140 5 5 F
20 135 5 5 F
30 135 5 5 F
35 135 5 5 F
85 135 5 5 F
100 135 5 5 F
110 135 5 5 F
145 135 5 5 F
150 135 5 5 F
170 135 5 5 F
180 135 5 5 F
190 135 5 5 F
230 135 5 5 F
235 135 5 5 F
30 130 5 5 F
65 130 5 5 F
70 130 5 5 F
95 130 5 5 F
100 130 5 5 F
105 130 5 5 F
155 130 5 5 F
165 130 5 5 F
170 130 5 5 F
175 130 5 5 F
180 130 5 5 F
185 130 5 5 F
195 130 5 5 F
225 130 5 5 F
30 125 5 5 F
35 125 5 5 F
70 125 5 5 F
75 125 5 5 F
80 125 5 5 F
85 125 5 5 F
100 125 5 5 F
160 125 5 5 F
165 125 5 5 F
175 125 5 5 F
180 125 5 5 F
185 125 5 5 F
195 125 5 5 F
230 125 5 5 F
235 125 5 5 F
30 120 5 5 F
35 120 5 5 F
80 120 5 5 F
105 120 5 5 F
115 120 5 5 F
145 120 5 5 F
155 120 5 5 F
165 120 5 5 F
170 120 5 5 F
175 120 5 5 F
190 120 5 5 F
225 120 5 5 F
25 115 5 5 F
40 115 5 5 F
55 115 5 5 F
65 115 5 5 F
75 115 5 5 F
85 115 5 5 F
95 115 5 5 F
110 115 5 5 F
140 115 5 5 F
160 115 5 5 F
165 115 5 5 F
170 115 5 5 F
175 115 5 5 F
195 115 5 5 F
210 115 5 5 F
215 115 5 5 F
230 115 5 5 F
235 115 5 5 F
240 115 5 5 F
35 110 5 5 F
85 110 5 5 F
90 110 5 5 F
110 110 5 5 F
120 110 5 5 F
125 110 5 5 F
135 110 5 5 F
140 110 5 5 F
185 110 5 5 F
190 110 5 5 F
195 110 5 5 F
205 110 5 5 F
210 110 5 5 F
225 110 5 5 F
230 110 5 5 F
235 110 5 5 F
25 105 5 5 F
30 105 5 5 F
45 105 5 5 F
60 105 5 5 F
65 105 5 5 F
70 105 5 5 F
75 105 5 5 F
90 105 5 5 F
95 105 5 5 F
105 105 5 5 F
110 105 5 5 F
140 105 5 5 F
155 105 5 5 F
165 105 5 5 F
175 105 5 5 F
185 105 5 5 F
195 105 5 5 F
215 105 5 5 F
230 105 5 5 F
20 100 5 5 F
35 100 5 5 F
45 100 5 5 F
60 100 5 5 F
70 100 5 5 F
80 100 5 5 F
85 100 5 5 F
90 100 5 5 F
110 100 5 5 F
125 100 5 5 F
135 100 5 5 F
140 100 5 5 F
145 100 5 5 F
160 100 5 5 F
200 100 5 5 F
210 100 5 5 F
220 100 5 5 F
225 100 5 5 F
230 100 5 5 F
240 100 5 5 F
20 95 5 5 F
25 95 5 5 F
30 95 5 5 F
40 95 5 5 F
45 95 5 5 F
55 95 5 5 F
70 95 5 5 F
75 95 5 5 F
95 95 5 5 F
105 95 5 5 F
110 95 5 5 F
120 95 5 5 F
140 95 5 5 F
155 95 5 5 F
160 95 5 5 F
165 95 5 5 F
175 95 5 5 F
185 95 5 5 F
205 95 5 5 F
20 90 5 5 F
25 90 5 5 F
30 90 5 5 F
45 90 5 5 F
55 90 5 5 F
60 90 5 5 F
65 90 5 5 F
85 90 5 5 F
90 90 5 5 F
110 90 5 5 F
115 90 5 5 F
130 90 5 5 F
140 90 5 5 F
145 90 5 5 F
160 90 5 5 F
170 90 5 5 F
205 90 5 5 F
220 90 5 5 F
235 90 5 5 F
240 90 5 5 F
25 85 5 5 F
35 85 5 5 F
40 85 5 5 F
55 85 5 5 F
60 85 5 5 F
65 85 5 5 F
70 85 5 5 F
75 85 5 5 F
90 85 5 5 F
95 85 5 5 F
105 85 5 5 F
110 85 5 5 F
115 85 5 5 F
120 85 5 5 F
125 85 5 5 F
130 85 5 5 F
135 85 5 5 F
145 85 5 5 F
150 85 5 5 F
160 85 5 5 F
165 85 5 5 F
170 85 5 5 F
180 85 5 5 F
190 85 5 5 F
200 85 5 5 F
210 85 5 5 F
230 85 5 5 F
240 85 5 5 F
20 80 5 5 F
35 80 5 5 F
40 80 5 5 F
45 80 5 5 F
55 80 5 5 F
65 80 5 5 F
75 80 5 5 F
80 80 5 5 F
85 80 5 5 F
90 80 5 5 F
95 80 5 5 F
110 80 5 5 F
115 80 5 5 F
130 80 5 5 F
150 80 5 5 F
170 80 5 5 F
175 80 5 5 F
190 80 5 5 F
215 80 5 5 F
235 80 5 5 F
240 80 5 5 F
20 75 5 5 F
30 75 5 5 F
45 75 5 5 F
55 75 5 5 F
80 75 5 5 F
100 75 5 5 F
105 75 5 5 F
110 75 5 5 F
120 75 5 5 F
125 75 5 5 F
135 75 5 5 F
145 75 5 5 F
150 75 5 5 F
155 75 5 5 F
165 75 5 5 F
170 75 5 5 F
175 75 5 5 F
180 75 5 5 F
200 75 5 5 F
205 75 5 5 F
220 75 5 5 F
225 75 5 5 F
240 75 5 5 F
55 70 5 5 F
60 70 5 5 F
65 70 5 5 F
75 70 5 5 F
80 70 5 5 F
95 70 5 5 F
100 70 5 5 F
105 70 5 5 F
115 70 5 5 F
130 70 5 5 F
140 70 5 5 F
165 70 5 5 F
170 70 5 5 F
175 70 5 5 F
185 70 5 5 F
190 70 5 5 F
215 70 5 5 F
220 70 5 5 F
235 70 5 5 F
70 65 5 5 F
80 65 5 5 F
85 65 5 5 F
100 65 5 5 F
115 65 5 5 F
120 65 5 5 F
125 65 5 5 F
130 65 5 5 F
135 65 5 5 F
145 65 5 5 F
150 65 5 5 F
170 65 5 5 F
190 65 5 5 F
195 65 5 5 F
205 65 5 5 F
220 65 5 5 F
225 65 5 5 F
235 65 5 5 F
240 65 5 5 F
70 60 5 5 F
75 60 5 5 F
80 60 5 5 F
95 60 5 5 F
105 60 5 5 F
115 60 5 5 F
150 60 5 5 F
155 60 5 5 F
165 60 5 5 F
170 60 5 5 F
175 60 5 5 F
180 60 5 5 F
185 60 5 5 F
190 60 5 5 F
230 60 5 5 F
240 60 5 5 F
65 55 5 5 F
80 55 5 5 F
85 55 5 5 F
100 55 5 5 F
110 55 5 5 F
115 55 5 5 F
145 55 5 5 F
150 55 5 5 F
170 55 5 5 F
180 55 5 5 F
190 55 5 5 F
195 55 5 5 F
225 55 5 5 F
235 55 5 5 F
75 50 5 5 F
80 50 5 5 F
95 50 5 5 F
100 50 5 5 F
105 50 5 5 F
155 50 5 5 F
165 50 5 5 F
170 50 5 5 F
175 50 5 5 F
180 50 5 5 F
185 50 5 5 F
225 50 5 5 F
80 45 5 5 F
85 45 5 5 F
100 45 5 5 F
160 45 5 5 F
170 45 5 5 F
175 45 5 5 F
180 45 5 5 F
190 45 5 5 F
195 45 5 5 F
230 45 5 5 F
235 45 5 5 F
70 40 5 5 F
80 40 5 5 F
105 40 5 5 F
145 40 5 5 F
155 40 5 5 F
165 40 5 5 F
170 40 5 5 F
175 40 5 5 F
75 35 5 5 F
85 35 5 5 F
95 35 5 5 F
110 35 5 5 F
115 35 5 5 F
130 35 5 5 F
160 35 5 5 F
165 35 5 5 F
170 35 5 5 F
175 35 5 5 F
180 35 5 5 F
185 35 5 5 F
200 35 5 5 F
205 35 5 5 F
210 35 5 5 F
220 35 5 5 F
230 35 5 5 F
240 35 5 5 F
70 30 5 5 F
85 30 5 5 F
90 30 5 5 F
110 30 5 5 F
125 30 5 5 F
135 30 5 5 F
145 30 5 5 F
165 30 5 5 F
175 30 5 5 F
180 30 5 5 F
185 30 5 5 F
190 30 5 5 F
195 30 5 5 F
205 30 5 5 F
210 30 5 5 F
225 30 5 5 F
230 30 5 5 F
65 25 5 5 F
70 25 5 5 F
75 25 5 5 F
90 25 5 5 F
95 25 5 5 F
105 25 5 5 F
110 25 5 5 F
115 25 5 5 F
125 25 5 5 F
135 25 5 5 F
140 25 5 5 F
155 25 5 5 F
165 25 5 5 F
175 25 5 5 F
185 25 5 5 F
205 25 5 5 F
220 25 5 5 F
230 25 5 5 F
70 20 5 5 F
80 20 5 5 F
85 20 5 5 F
90 20 5 5 F
110 20 5 5 F
140 20 5 5 F
145 20 5 5 F
160 20 5 5 F
195 20 5 5 F
205 20 5 5 F
210 20 5 5 F
220 20 5 5 F
225 20 5 5 F
230 20 5 5 F
235 20 5 5 F
0.000000 0.247059 1.000000 R
20 240 5 5 F
25 240 5 5 F
30 240 5 5 F
35 240 5 5 F
40 240 5 5 F
45 240 5 5 F
50 240 5 5 F
210 240 5 5 F
215 240 5 5 F
220 240 5 5 F
225 240 5 5 F
230 240 5 5 F
235 240 5 5 F
240 240 5 5 F
20 235 5 5 F
50 235 5 5 F
210 235 5 5 F
240 235 5 5 F
20 230 5 5 F
50 230 5 5 F
210 230 5 5 F
240 230 5 5 F
20 225 5 5 F
50 225 5 5 F
210 225 5 5 F
240 225 5 5 F
20 220 5 5 F
50 220 5 5 F
210 220 5 5 F
240 220 5 5 F
20 215 5 5 F
50 215 5 5 F
210 215 5 5 F
240 215 5 5 F
20 210 5 5 F
25 210 5 5 F
30 210 5 5 F
35 210 5 5 F
40 210 5 5 F
45 210 5 5 F
50 210 5 5 F
210 210 5 5 F
215 210 5 5 F
220 210 5 5 F
225 210 5 5 F
230 210 5 5 F
235 210 5 5 F
240 210 5 5 F
20 50 5 5 F
25 50 5 5 F
30 50 5 5 F
35 50 5 5 F
40 50 5 5 F
45 50 5 5 F
50 50 5 5 F
20 45 5 5 F
50 45 5 5 F
20 40 5 5 F
50 40 5 5 F
20 35 5 5 F
50 35 5 5 F
20 30 5 5 F
50 30 5 5 F
20 25 5 5 F
50 25 5 5 F
20 20 5 5 F
25 20 5 5 F
30 20 5 5 F
35 20 5 5 F
40 20 5 5 F
45 20 5 5 F
50 20 5 5 F
1.000000 0.000000 1.000000 R
120 220 5 5 F
125 220 5 5 F
130 220 5 5 F
135 220 5 5 F
140 220 5 5 F
120 215 5 5 F
140 215 5 5 F
120 210 5 5 F
130 210 5 5 F
140 210 5 5 F
120 205 5 5 F
140 205 5 5 F
120 200 5 5 F
125 200 5 5 F
130 200 5 5 F
135 200 5 5 F
140 200 5 5 F
40 140 5 5 F
45 140 5 5 F
50 140 5 5 F
55 140 5 5 F
60 140 5 5 F
120 140 5 5 F
125 140 5 5 F
130 140 5 5 F
135 140 5 5 F
140 140 5 5 F
200 140 5 5 F
205 140 5 5 F
210 140 5 5 F
215 140 5 5 F
220 140 5 5 F
40 135 5 5 F
60 135 5 5 F
120 135 5 5 F
140 135 5 5 F
200 135 5 5 F
220 135 5 5 F
40 130 5 5 F
50 130 5 5 F
60 130 5 5 F
120 130 5 5 F
130 130 5 5 F
140 130 5 5 F
200 130 5 5 F
210 130 5 5 F
220 130 5 5 F
40 125 5 5 F
60 125 5 5 F
120 125 5 5 F
140 125 5 5 F
200 125 5 5 F
220 125 5 5 F
40 120 5 5 F
45 120 5 5 F
50 120 5 5 F
55 120 5 5 F
60 120 5 5 F
120 120 5 5 F
125 120 5 5 F
130 120 5 5 F
135 120 5 5 F
140 120 5 5 F
200 120 5 5 F
205 120 5 5 F
210 120 5 5 F
215 120 5 5 F
220 120 5 5 F
120 60 5 5 F
125 60 5 5 F
130 60 5 5 F
135 60 5 5 F
140 60 5 5 F
200 60 5 5 F
205 60 5 5 F
210 60 5 5 F
215 60 5 5 F
220 60 5 5 F
120 55 5 5 F
140 55 5 5 F
200 55 5 5 F
220 55 5 5 F
120 50 5 5 F
130 50 5 5 F
140 50 5 5 F
200 50 5 5 F
210 50 5 5 F
220 50 5 5 F
120 45 5 5 F
140 45 5 5 F
200 45 5 5 F
220 45 5 5 F
120 40 5 5 F
125 40 5 5 F
130 40 5 5 F
135 40 5 5 F
140 40 5 5 F
200 40 5 5 F
205 40 5 5 F
210 40 5 5 F
215 40 5 5 F
220 40 5 5 F
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 R
60 210 5 5 F
70 210 5 5 F
80 210 5 5 F
90 210 5 5 F
100 210 5 5 F
110 210 5 5 F
150 210 5 5 F
160 210 5 5 F
170 210 5 5 F
180 210 5 5 F
190 210 5 5 F
200 210 5 5 F
50 200 5 5 F
50 190 5 5 F
50 180 5 5 F
50 170 5 5 F
50 160 5 5 F
50 150 5 5 F
50 110 5 5 F
50 100 5 5 F
50 90 5 5 F
50 80 5 5 F
50 70 5 5 F
50 60 5 5 F
0.262745 0.623529 0.329412 R
60 235 5 5 F
60 225 5 5 F
60 215 5 5 F
20 200 5 5 F
25 200 5 5 F
30 200 5 5 F
35 200 5 5 F
40 200 5 5 F
55 200 5 5 F
60 200 5 5 F
205 200 5 5 F
215 200 5 5 F
225 200 5 5 F
235 200 5 5 F
60 50 5 5 F
60 40 5 5 F
60 35 5 5 F
60 30 5 5 F
60 25 5 5 F
60 20 5 5 F
0.243137 0.682353 0.745098 R
200 240 5 5 F
195 235 5 5 F
195 230 5 5 F
195 225 5 5 F
200 225 5 5 F
190 220 5 5 F
195 220 5 5 F
200 220 5 5 F
40 70 5 5 F
25 65 5 5 F
30 65 5 5 F
35 65 5 5 F
40 65 5 5 F
20 60 5 5 F
35 60 5 5 F
40 60 5 5 F
0.000000 0.247059 1.000000 R
30 230 5 5 F
35 230 5 5 F
40 230 5 5 F
220 230 5 5 F
225 230 5 5 F
230 230 5 5 F
30 225 5 5 F
35 225 5 5 F
40 225 5 5 F
220 225 5 5 F
225 225 5 5 F
230 225 5 5 F
30 220 5 5 F
35 220 5 5 F
40 220 5 5 F
220 220 5 5 F
225 220 5 5 F
230 220 5 5 F
30 40 5 5 F
35 40 5 5 F
40 40 5 5 F
30 35 5 5 F
35 35 5 5 F
40 35 5 5 F
30 30 5 5 F
35 30 5 5 F
40 30 5 5 F
%%EOF


As I mentioned in the comments, I tested it with this exact example which is found in the docs. It still outputs me the same thing

no you are not..... read comment and check the difference  or even just copy, paste and test it man

My sincere apologies sir. You're completely right. I just looked at your code and my reaction was "This looks exactly like the example I found in examples/eps.php. Since I copy pasted that example which gave me the output provided by me, I saw no need to copy your code aswell. It was that little detail that it's named "outputType" and not "outputInterface" which looked the same to me on first sight. Thank you so much and I am really sorry for this mistake!

you are welcome,I'm glad it was useful to you
